# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level please help solve

Tags: python-3.x

when i run my code is get IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

```
       if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if bullet_state == "ready":
                    bulletX = playerX
                    fire_bullet(playerX, bulletY)
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -0.3
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You have space at the beginning everywhere! Also, sometimes there is inconsistent spacing meaning you used tabs somewhere and spaces somewhere else. Depending on the editor you are using, it does not correct it.

following should work:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        if bullet_state == "ready":
            bulletX = playerX
            fire_bullet(playerX, bulletY)
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        playerX_change = -0.3
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        playerX_change = 0.3
```